# Aws S3 to Databricks mount is not working

Tags: databricks, aws-databricks

I have mounted 'mybucket' using mount commands and i could able to list all the objects using the below command-

```
%fs
ls /mnt/mybucket/
```

however, i have folders inside the folders in 'mybucket' and i want to run the below command but it is not working.

```
%fs
ls /mnt/mybucket/*/*/
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: %fs ls /mnt/mybucket/*/*/

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Hi Alex, i am getting this error- java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory: /*/*/

Comment: @KiranAnnamaneni - please check my below answer . nested mounts are not supported in Databricks

Answer (score 0):

The `dbutils.fs.ls` and it's magic variant `%fs ls` don't support wildcards, so you need to iterate over the files yourself, with something like this:

```py
def list_files(path, max_level = 1, cur_level=0):
  d = dbutils.fs.ls(path)
  for i in d:
    if i.name.endswith("/") and i.size == 0 and cur_level < (max_level - 1):
      yield from list_files(i.path, max_level, cur_level+1)
    else:
      yield i.path

files = list_files("/mnt/mybucket", 1)
```

Comment: Thanks Alex for the reply. I will try this

Answer (score 0):

If you attempt to create a mount point within an existing mount point, for example:

Mount one storage account to `/mnt/storage1`

Mount a second storage account to `/mnt/storage1/storage2`

This will fail because nested mounts are not supported in Databricks. recommended one is creating separate mount entries for each storage object.

For example:

Mount one storage account to `/mnt/storage1`

Mount a second storage account to `/mnt/storage2`

Answer (score 0):

Unmount and mount again.

```
dbutils.fs.unmount("/mnt/mount_name")

dbutils.fs.mount("s3a://%s" % aws_bucket_name, "/mnt/%s" % mount_name)
```